# How to create SSRS Pie chart with only 2 report items, or 2 values

Tags: reporting-services

How to create SSRS Pie chart with only 2 report items, or 2 values
the attached pic show the 2 expression report items which represents % complete, and the remaining of 100%

it asks for category, but there is no category, just 2 values

I tried to add 2 report items on values,
it keeps asking for the category

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXVx6.jpg)

Comment: What do the 2 values represent? Can you give examples?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show a sample of the data. This should be the results of your dataset query.

Comment: the attached pic show the 2 expression report items which represents % complete, and the remaining of 100%